# keyup or change event on input hidden is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the Hidden input takes its value from a text input, how can I monitor the change and implement something when changing the Hidden core value?
example:

```js
$('#input2').on('keyup, change', function () {
    $('#input1').val($(this).val());
});
$('#input1').on('keyup, change', function () {
    $('#div').text( $('#input1').val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" value="test" id="input1" />
<input type="text" value="test" id="input2" />
<div id="div">loading...</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fire keyup explicitly using:

```
$('#input2').on('keyup, change', function () {
        $('#input1').val($(this).val());
//Add this line
        $('#input1').trigger("keyup");

});
$('#input1').on('keyup, change', function () {
        $('#div').text( $('#input1').val() );
});
```

You have to just add this line:

$('#input1').trigger("keyup");

Answer (score 1):

The change event is fired only when user inputs the text . You may have to manually fire the change event on hidden input

Here as input1 is set with value of input2 the div will be updated with what user types in the the input2

Refer below

```js
$("#input2").on("keyup change", function () {
  
  $("#input1").val($(this).val());
 
 //after setting input1 value fire the change event on it 
 //to change the text in div with the value of inoput1
  $("#input1").change();
});
$("#input1").on("keyup change", function () {
  $("#div").text($("#input1").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input type="hidden" value="test" id="input1" />
    <input type="text" value="test" id="input2" />
    <div id="div">loading...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The onchange event is a user event. It will not fire if you change the value by script.

It will certainly not fire when changed by the code behind. Since it is a client event.

also you have miss using of .ON JQUERY function,

```html
 $('#input2').on('keyup, change', **/*'ELEMENT_SELECTOR'*/** function () {
```

any way you can Circumvent by doing that:

```html
$(document).on('change, keyup', '#input2', function () {
    $('#input1').val($(this).val());
        $('#div').html( $('#input1').val() );
});
```